# Ducati Monster 821 - Ignition problems

Tags: motorcycle, immobilizer, ducati, monster

I have a 2015-Ducati Monster 821 that have started to argue with me. 
When i turn the key to on - i see the panel light up and the fuel pump etc starts. But when i klick the ignition button, nothing happens. engine starter dont turn, nothing.

I have tried taking the key out and in again a couple of times and suddenly it will start.

The bike has been in neutral and the kickstand up. I have checked for loose wiring but all seems good. 
Could it be a problem with the imobalizer in the key? Any other ideas?

Comment: Try eliminate ignition button failure.

Comment: @krzyski - how can i do that?

Comment: disassembly switch, disconnect button and contact bare wires to start.

Comment: btw...welcome to the site!  Thanks for the question.  Cheers!

Comment: Did the dealer ever resolve your issue?

Comment: They have orderd a new part. But i also complainted about poor power and a high "sssshh" sound ( yeah - thats right. i tryed to write the sound!). So they found out that i needed valve check also. going to take a hole day. And it is summer now .. so i dont know yet when they have the possibility to take my bike in for service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You stated that you can get it to start**

You need to fuss with the ignition switch and move the key in and out in order to get it to start.  More than likely something to do with the physical interface between the switch and the contacts within it.

I only say this is more likely because it is physical and things that are physical/analogue have a higher tendency of failure than an RFID inside a key.

Since you have a 2015 model year, perhaps you can take it to Ducati and have them do some warranty work.

IF you choose to mess with it and make the issue worse  and they can detect you did the work, you may void your warranty.

Comment: Hmm yeah that is true.. I will contact the dealership , and have them check it up.

Answer (score 2):

So i followed DucatiKiller's answer and sent it in to the dealership. They have no clue to what the problem can be - but are changing the starter. We will see how it will work out.

New update ! ! Edit ;
So they changed the starter and it worked about 1 month, and then it just went complete dead.. So it went back in, and now they have changed the ignition button. Time will show if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your battery first , mostly with your issue most of the sources are with the batteries , kindly check also your ignition coil or do a jumpstart just to check.